# Circular Seekbar with two range thumbs

Tags: java, android, xml, seekbar

Can somebody please help me create a Circular SeekBar like this one(given in the image).
It is a double thumb Seekbar with a range and has max 70 and a minimum of 10 value. also the image present inside changes according to the change in the range of values.
Please help...

[This image consists of full range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQzNA.jpg)

[This image shows some random range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECenA.jpg)

Comment: On Stackoverflow you always need to attach a minimalistic example of your attempt and ask about the specific coding problem you ran into.

Comment: I'm not able to proceed to get the Circular Seekbar with two thumbs. I tried a few things such as a circular seekbar but wasn't able to make two thumbs also tried searching the internet but no use. Can You please help?

Answer (score -1):

I found this library, maybe it can help you.
https://github.com/yingLanNull/CircleAlarmTimerView

[image: CircleAlarmTimerView]

Comment: I would like to thank you for your effort but, this link is not what I require. It does provide a circular seekbar with 2 thumbs but doesn't solve my problem. In this, it doesn't give the range and instead shows time. I want to present the age as seekbar value changes. Please refer to the image...that is exactly what I'm trying to look for.